I upgraded from 22.04 -> 23.10 -> 24.04. App center not installed. I still see old "Ubuntu Software"
I recently upgraded from 22.04 Lts to 23.10 and instantly to 24.04. I was facing problelm in directly upgrading to 24.04. After the upgrade everything works perfectly fine. Only problem is I don't see the new "App Center" everyone is talking about. I still have the old "Ubuntu Software" installed. I tried installing it separately but could not do it.

Does this answer your question? Upgaded.. But instead run - sudo snap refresh snap-store --channel=latest/stable/ubuntu-24.04

this fixed it for me. thank you

Does this answer your question? Upgraded (from 23.04) to Ubuntu 23.10 - no App Center, no firmware flashing tool

Does this answer your question? Cannot upgrade from Ubuntu 23.10 or 22.04 to Ubuntu 24.04
